# Concerning Brane cosmology

Tags: physics, spacetime-dimensions, quantum, dimensions

EDIT:  If an actor or object in a higher dimensional space with less mass than say, my car, attached itself to the car through our dimension's membrane, would it be able to move the car or hold it in a fixed (but normally unnatural position such as in midair) by moving around in bulk space?

In other words, does the dimension n+1 position of the attached actor or object supersede changes of position in dimension n regardless of the affected object's mass?

Hope this makes more sense... crazy stuff!

OP:  I searched much for this specific and odd question concerning physical interactions with the Bulk in brane theory, but haven't come up with anything.

If one had the ability to stick a pin or beam attached to an object out from a brane and into the bulk, would the attached object's global position then be dictated by its bulk coordinates?  In other words, could one use this trick to fix the object in 3D space (for instance appearing to make something levitate), or would the beam be dragged around the brane's membrane/surface if it moved in local space?

This stuff is so interesting but abstract to me.  I hope the Q makes sense.

Comment: afaik branes are purely conjectural stuff... so, what do you hope to get from us?

Comment: This is *really* a question for physics.SE. (Or maybe astronomy.SE.)

Comment: cool, thought it was worth a try since I've seen some really awesome and detailed answers here in worldbuilding.  @L.Dutch Hope for insight from awesome, intelligent people ;)

Comment: Sorry to say, but I really don't get what you are actually asking.

Comment: As @L.Dutch mentioned, this is all conjecture at the moment. I think for us to help you develop your magic or science-based magic system you would have to give a more detailed description of what you hope would happen and how you need it to work and then we can reality-check it for you. Then you may get the nice detailed answers :)

Comment: @Molot so say I'm a 2D entity on a bulletin board, and you reach out an affix a little pin to my body.  Because the 3D pin has coordinates I cannot alter, I am now stuck at that position on the board until you remove the pin. I'm wondering if this works in the n+1 dimension direction.  If someone puts a pin in me, am I stuck where I am, or does the pin move in bulk space when I move within our brane?

Comment: @EveryBitHelps I want to appear to levitate objects by essentially 'pinning' them to the outer surface of our dimension.  Maybe this makes it more complicated than it needs to be if we're just going to call it levitation, but I was thinking poking an appendage out into the bulk would be a one-time action, requiring no further energy input.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to reopen, but before I do, can you provide an example of someone in our 3D space "pinning" a 2D object (making this work in the n-1 space)?  I could easily be wrong, but I don't know of any actual 2D objects that we can manipulate, much less manipulate in the manner you suggest.  If there's no example, then this question can't be reopened since it would be primarily opinion-based (no factual reference from which to derive a fiction-based answer).  If there is an example, I'm delighted to VTR.

Comment: @JBH I gave an example above, though I know that's not truly 2D.  I'm not sure a sufficient example exists, tbh.  I'd found no indication this was an idea touched on by details in the theory, but it gets so far beyond my math skills I can only follow to a point before needing translations.  Anyway, I'll keep up the search.

Comment: The reason I ask is that our inability to act upon a true 2D world would suggest that a 4D person cannot act upon the 3D world.  The idea is fascinating and, frankly, if you can come up with a suspension-of-disbelief example of 3D-to-2D in your book, then the premise is fabulous and you should run with it.  Regrettably, it also makes it a very difficult question to answer within the Stack Exchange context.